# interpolation of filter coefficients

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, interpolation

i've read that it is possible to interpolate between two sets of filter coefficients (if they are close of course), but how to interpolate between two sets of coefficients which are of different orders? Is it possible ? If not what is the possible way to fade between two IIR filters ?

thanks

Jeff